# XSLT for CoreResultsWebPart

Tags: search

I've created a custom page for my advanced search using

```
<SEARCHWC:AdvancedSearchBox webpart="true" runat="server" __WebPartId="{FDC8E1FF-48ED-4754-84A2-E81BDEE4B4E1}" id="AdvancedSearchBox1">
        <WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
          ..........
```

and have used

```
 <SearchWC:CoreResultsWebPart runat="server" FrameType="None" />
```

on my results page. Does anyone know how I can pass XSLT to CoreResultsWebPart so that I can format the results?

Answer (score 2):

You can export the coreresultswebpart. In the .webpart file use the XslLink property of type string to point to your custom xsl file.